# Can't handle onChange event on color picker

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the plugin color picker provided by: [eyecon](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/#implement)
Basically what I'm trying to do is get the `hex` color of the control each time the user change the color on the `ColorPicker`. This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/colorpicker.css" type="text/css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="css/layout.css" />
<title>ColorPicker - jQuery plugin</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/colorpicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/eye.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/utils.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/layout.js?ver=1.0.2"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="colorSelector"><div style="background-color: rgb(62, 62, 189); "></div></div>
<input type="text" maxlength="6" size="6" id="mycolor" value="00ff00">
</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    console.log("Function enabled");
    var currentHex = '#38ff56';

    $('#colorSelector').ColorPicker(
    {
        color: currentHex,
        onShow: function(colpkr) 
        {
            $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
            return false;
        },
        onHide: function(colpkr) 
        {
            $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
            return false;
        },
        onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb) 
        {
            $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
            $('#mycolor').val(hex);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

But seems that the `onChange`event isn't trigger.. no console error and in the network all library component are loaded correctly. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The other events are triggered? Did you have any errors on your console? The color picker is being loaded correctly?

Comment: All is loaded correctly and also I not have any error in the console.

Comment: Don't lie. Nothing is loaded correctly according with your comments in the answers. Please, we can help you, but you need to be as colaborating as possible.

Comment: Why I should lie? You're fun I came here for search help. If you want the try I can allow you to access with team viewer. As I said all is loaded correctly, the methods inside the "document" of JQuery isn't loaded, not working for me. Also work the $(document).ready(function(), infact I can see in the console "Function enabled". Later nothing happean. Believe in me man and peel away the downvote.

Comment: Look at this: I said: `The other events are triggered? Did you have any errors on your console? The color picker is being loaded correctly?`. And your answer: `All is loaded correctly and also I not have any error in the console.` And then in the answers below: `The event is also not triggered the code doesn't enter in: onShow, onHide, onChange this is the problem man`. In don't downvote you.

Comment: Try my first answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33056854/5035890

Comment: I recommend to you to use another plugin. The plugin are you using are of year 2009, it's discontinuated, and maybe are a conflict with your jquery.

Comment: So I guess there is a misunderstading 'cause when I say: "all is loaded correctly" I mean that all the plugins component are loaded without problem not that the events work. Infact if your read later I've said this... I've tried also your answers but nothing has worked. When I change the color the event isn't triggered so I can't get the value from JQuery.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91926/discussion-between-dillinger-and-marcos-perez-gude).

Comment: I'm here. Give a comment if you have problems with the other plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is adding the css I gues

Change this:

```
    $('#colorSelector div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
```

By this:

```
    $('#colorSelector div').css('background-color', '#' + hex);
```

Comment: The event is also not triggered the code doesn't enter in: onShow, onHide, onChange this is the problem man

Comment: This change is neccessary, because `backgroundColor` is not a property of css. You said to me that the other events are triggered in the comment of the post. Something wrong you are making. Try my another answer instancing the color picker in the input and not in the div

Comment: which post? I mean the $(document).ready(function() is triggered but the other method inside of it nope.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your selector:

```
 $('#mycolor').ColorPicker({
     options
  });
```

Comment: If this doesn't works, try to reproduce the problem in jsfiddle.net and share with us.

Answer (score 0):

try with

```
$('#colorSelector div').css('background-color', '#' + hex);
```

and are you sure you have to put the '#' before hex?

Comment: Yeah but this isn't my problem. The main problem is that the event  onShow, onHide, onChange isn't triggered as I said in the post.